# Can we nest a component containing routes inside Routes component from react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-routing

I am trying to upgrade react router package from version 5 to 6. I have replaced `Switch` to `Routes` as below:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/editor"> // takes to the editor route
    {Some component}     
  </Route>
  <ComponentA />
</Switch>
```

This `ComponentA` used to have another `Switch` which had more `Route` components defined, but now it doesn't allow to have `Routes` under `Routes` (previously `Switch` under a `Switch` was allowed), nor does it allow to have `Fragment`s.

`ComponentA` looks like below:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/abc"></Route>
  <Route path="/xyz"></Route>
</Switch>
```

How can we define a component having more than one `Route` inside `Routes`?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render what are called descendent routes. I would say it would/could look something like the following where `ComponentA` is rendered into a route that matches some other base path, e.g. `path="*"` or `path="/*"` or `path="/otherSubRoute/*"`, etc. Notice the important part here is the trailing `"*"` wildcard character so any descendent routes can also be matched and rendered.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/editor" element={Some component} />
  <Route path="*" element={<ComponentA />} />
</Routes>
```

ComponentA

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/abc" element={....} /> // "*/abc" where * is parent route path
  <Route path="/xyz" element={....} /> // "*/xyz" where * is parent route path
</Routes>
```